# Double Interpolation of Array in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script so that I can easily add host types to it without changing the code itself.  Each type of host has a specific group of id's and templates associated with it.  Here is the cod that I have derived:

```
CLASS="memcache"
memcache_template=( 42 45 )
CLASS_template=${CLASS}_template
template=$( eval echo $`echo $CLASS_template` )

for i in  ${template[@]}; do
  echo $i
done
```

The output that I get is just "42".  I need it to output both 42 and 45.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
CLASS="memcache"
memcache_template=(42 45)

CLASS_template=${CLASS}_template[@]

for i in ${!CLASS_template}; do
  echo $i
done
```

See the discussion of variable indirection in `info "(bash)Shell Parameter Expansion"`. Note that you cannot use `${!CLASS_template[@]}` because that has a special meaning. The array subscripting must be done before indirection.

Comment: Neat!  Also, you could put memcache_template's contents into a new array (more similar to the code in the question) with `template=("${!CLASS_template}")`

Comment: Actually, I found that I can skip a whole step.  I simply defined `template=( "${CLASS}_template[@]" )`.